# Spring Roo Refactor Pull Out ITDs

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, eclipse-plugin, spring-roo

I did a Refactor push in to ***Item_Roo_DbManaged.aj*** file, and its content was moved to ***Item.java*** domain, but I'm not able to undo the puch in process, I tried right-click on Item.java and Refactor > Pull.. but there is just a Pull Up option menu, Pull Out ITDs option doesn't exist anymore. So, I tried to undo the push in process, how can I do it (manually is not an option) ?

STS 3.5 (Eclipse Kepler), Spring Roo 1.2.4

Thanks.
--JR

Comment: You should probably have had your files under version control. The reverting would have been a piece of cake. Have you tried the local history of STS to see whether or not the deleted aspects are there?

Comment: I did, but didn't work, what I did is to delete the Item.java content and I created the .aj file manually, and its content was populated again automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the pushed method on **Item.java** and relaunch **ROO shell**.

Roo will regenerate the pushed method on **Item_Roo_DbManaged.aj**.

Best Regards,